# .scr file and APDU

Tags: testing, netbeans, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I am using JCard sim, java card version 2.2.2 and I want to know how the .scr file is associated with the .java file. (the java card simulator on NetBeans IDE. I am not using an actual smartcard).

If someone can provide me with some useful links on how these two files are related, I would greatly appreciate it.
I have looked through the following links, but they were not specifically helpful in illustrating how I can modify the .scr file in association with my .java file

[C H A P T E R 5 - Converting Java Class Files](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/kit-user-2.2.2/cJDKconverter.html)

[How to write a Java Card applet: A developer's guide - JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-1999/jw-07-javacard.html)

Basically what I am trying to do is create a test applet (without the need of .scr files to send and receive APDUs by my other files)
     - I want to be able to read APDU which contains the the parameters for a function in my process method
     - That function will then create another APDU as its output, which another function will read as one of it's parameters

As far as I understand, the .scr file is used to send command APDUs that is read by the applet, but there is no way to write to the .scr file.
How can I create my own .java test file that sends and receives APDUs instead of relying on the .scr?
I can provide more details of what my code looks, if absolutely required.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `javax.smartcardio` service that is added using `Security.addProvider()`? You can look for that in the source code...

Comment: Since I'm using a simulator, I don't think I can use this particular API (it requires the use of a real smart card). Do you have any other suggestions about how to test, without using an .scr file (or how to internally create an script file in my program)

Comment: No, I meant [this](https://jcardsim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html). jCardSim implements a virtual terminal used through `javax.smartcardio`.

Comment: Were you able to test drive the interface? Should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate with the simulator using the method described in the [quick start guide of jCardSim](http://jcardsim.org/docs/quick-start-guide-simulator-api). It is also described how to select an Applet using the correct AID in there. The inherited `process(APDU)` method will receive any APDU send using the methods described in the quick start guide, starting with the SELECT by NAME APDU (`INS` = `A4`). After that it is normal APDU processing.

Comment: Thanks for following up. At this time, we have decided not to use an external simulator, but are running into issues with the code, so we'll fix that before we start testing. The link is a good read, thank you.

Comment: You should not just abandon a question after you've asked it. Please try my solution and vote up or accept if it does what you were asking for.